# Memory addressing in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following code that multiplies num1 and num2 and then prints the result (the idea is to print the number 8, which is 56 in ascii), the 2 questions I would like to ask are marked as comments in the code.

```
section .text
    global _start     
_start:                   
    mov ecx, [num1]
    mov eax, [num2]
    mul ecx
    mov [result], eax  
    
    mov edx, 1
    mov ecx, result     ; 1. why it doesn't work if I replace the word result with eax.
                        ; 2. why it has to be "result" instead of "[result]" as with the previous
                             lines?
    mov ebx, 1  
    mov eax, 4      
    int 0x80   
    
    mov eax, 1    
    int 0x80 

section .data

num1 db 2
num2 db 28

section .bss

result resb 1
```

For the first question I would like to understand why I need to create an uninitialized variable first (result) to store the value I want to pass to ecx.

Comment: See the documentation for `SYS_WRITE`, it needs a *pointer* to the data (hence no brackets) as its second parameter (hence `ecx` per ABI).

Comment: *why I need to create an uninitialized variable* - You don't, but it has to be in memory.  You could use stack space.  e.g. `push eax` / `mov ecx, esp`.  Also, the BSS is zero-initialized on modern mainstream OSes, including Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would like to understand why I need to create an uninitialized variable first (result)*

It doesn't neccessarily be **uninitialized** but whenever you want to display something with `SYS_WRITE`, that something is required to be in memory (not in a register), as Margaret commented.

You have incorrectly defined your memory variables `num1, num2, result` with `db` or `resb`, which reserves 1 byte only (8 bits), but instructions

```
mov ecx, [num1]
mov eax, [num2]
mul ecx
```

all work with 4 bytes (32 bits).
Memory in your `section .data` contains something like `02 1C 00 00 00 00...` (in hexadecimal notation).

```
mov ecx, [num1] ; load 0x00001C02 to ECX.
mov eax, [num2] ; load 0x0000001C to EAX.
mul ecx         ; compute 0x00031038 to EAX and 0 to EDX.
```

You should either declare numbers as 32bits with

```
num1   DD  2
num2   DD 28
result DD  0
```

or load/store only the lowest eight bits of registers:

```
movzx ecx,[num1] ; load 0x00000002 to ECX.
movzx eax,[num2] ; load 0x0000001C to EAX.
mul ecx          ; compute 0x00000038 to EAX and 0 to EDX.
mov [result],AL  ; result will be 0x38 = 56 = '8'.
```

Comment: Since they're making a `write(fd=1, buf=result, len=1)` system call, `resb 1` is correct, and the bug is the store width.  (And also the load widths, true).  Apparently they want to output a single binary byte, which might just happen to be printable ASCII.  (`./a.out | hexdump -C` will work in the general case.)

Comment: Once you've gone to the trouble of zero-extending both inputs into 32-bit registers, you can use `imul eax,ecx`, unless you actually want to zero EDX and/or save a byte of code-size to use a slower one-operand `mul r32` instruction.  But if you care about code size instead of efficiency, you'd do `mov al, [num1]` / `mul byte [num2]`, or maybe `mov` the address into a register instead of using two `[disp32]` addressing modes.